# image comparison is not working after application did become active

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ios6

I am using following for comparing button's background image.

```
if([[button currentBackgroundImage] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]]){
      // do something
}
```

The code works fine when application is in active state. But when app gets back from idle state the above code doesn't work.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: in which method you use your code ?

Comment: i am using this code on button click

Comment: listen unnati ......i have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images don't compare after you come back from background because you're creating a new instance of that image for your comparison by using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]` (the images are compared by looking at their hash values, not by looking at the actual image contents). If you create a property for your image, when you first use imageNamed:, and use that in the comparison, it should work properly. So, I tested with this code, and it returned true when I checked after coming back from the background (I set the button's background image in IB).

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *greenButton;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *greenPng;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.greenPng = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
}

- (IBAction)checkImages:(id)sender {

    BOOL isTheSame = [self.greenButton.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:self.greenPng];
    NSLog(@"The images are %@",isTheSame? @"the same" : @"different");
    NSLog(@" button image hash is %d",self.greenButton.currentBackgroundImage.hash);
    NSLog(@" imageNamed image hash is %d",self.greenPng.hash);
}
```

**After Edit:**  I'm not sure my explanation is quite correct -- in one run of the app, you can make multiple calls to imageNamed:, and all the images that are returned will have the same hash (including the image you pick in IB, if you do it that way). I think this is due to cashing. In any case, when you come back from the background and call imageNamed: again, it returns an image with a different hash.